# How to correct this incremental constrain in cplex

Tags: cplex

How to correct this incremental constrains in the main because the below code gives me an error of (scripting run time error not of type 'lloNumVar ' because the Nchannel/ adj.beams may be an integer and fraction number.

```
 main
{
for(i in thisOplModel.beams)
{
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.beam_nomusedchannel[i],1);
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.Nchannels/thisOplModel.adj_beams[i],-1);
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setBounds(0,10000000)
  }  
  cplex.solve();
  thisOplModel.postProcess();          
subject to
{
 forall ( i in beams)
 ctEmpty:0<=0;
 //beam_nomusedchannel [i]  >= ceil (Nchannels/adjbeams[i]);
}
```

Comment: @  ALexfleischer

Comment: Nchannels and adjbeams are data or decision variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adjbeams and Nchannels are not decision variables you should turn

```
thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.Nchannels/thisOplModel.adj_beams[i],-1);
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setBounds(0,10000000)
```

into

```
//thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.Nchannels/thisOplModel.adj_beams[i],-1);
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setBounds(thisOplModel.Nchannels/thisOplModel.adj_beams[i],10000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main
{
for(i in thisOplModel.beams)
{
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.beam_nomusedchannel[i],1);
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setCoef(thisOplModel.Nchannels/thisOplModel.adj_beams[i],-1);
  thisOplModel.ctEmpty[i].setBounds(0,10000000)
  }  
  cplex.solve();
  thisOplModel.postProcess(); 

int Nchannels =20; // Nchannels is an integer number

         
subject to
{
 forall ( i in beams)
 ctEmpty:0<=0;
 //beam_nomusedchannel [i]  >= ceil (Nchannels/adjbeams[i]);
}

Execute
{
 //adjbeams[beams] is an after execute array; {11,15,7,6,5,4,3,1,12,...} 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).